# Spyde import module but not able to use it

Tags: python, module, loading

I am getting a very strange error and I can't really understand why.

I can successfully import a module named "filterpy", but when I run the code I get the error: module 'filterpy' has no attribute 'kalman'

Fun fact, the spyder editor tells me that such module exist, in fact it allows me to use even self-completion.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Gabriele

The code is below, the library can be installed with pip

```
import numpy as np
import filterpy as fp

def fx(x, dt):
     # state transition function - predict next state based
    # on constant velocity model x = vt + x_0
    F = np.array([[1, dt, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, dt], [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=float)
    return np.dot(F, x)

def hx(x):
    # measurement function - convert state into a measurement
   # where measurements are [x_pos, y_pos]
   return np.array([x[0], x[2]])

dt = 0.1
# create sigma points to use in the filter. This is standard for Gaussian processes
points = fp.kalman.MerweScaledSigmaPoints(4, alpha=.1, beta=2., kappa=-1)

kf = fp.kalman.UnscentedKalmanFilter(dim_x=4, dim_z=2, dt=dt, fx=fx, hx=hx, points=points)
kf.x = np.array([-1., 1., -1., 1]) # initial state
kf.P *= 0.2 # initial uncertainty
z_std = 0.1
kf.R = np.diag([z_std**2, z_std**2]) # 1 standard
kf.Q = fp.common.Q_discrete_white_noise(dim=2, dt=dt, var=0.01**2, block_size=2)

zs = [[i+np.random.randn()*z_std, i+np.random.randn()*z_std] for i in range(50)] # measurements
for z in zs:
    kf.predict()
    kf.update(z)
    print(kf.x, 'log-likelihood', kf.log_likelihood)
```

Comment: Can you check if changing the import statement to `from filterpy import kalman` changes anything?

Comment: Open the terminal and open python shell and try to import `kalman` see if the same error occurred.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that's very appreciated! importing kalamn in the console does not solve the problem, but the command from filterpy import kalman does. I just added that line before importing filterpy as fp, and the problem was solved. Do you know perhaps also why?